# Homebrew can't find /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to setup homebrew on my macbook with El Capitan with this command: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`. But I keep on getting this error message: `line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory`. I've tried following the steps listed in [this tutorial](http://digitizor.com/install-homebrew-osx-el-capitan/) but it made no difference. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Don't follow any random tutorial. Follow the README https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/

Comment: I have of course followed the readme as well, and when it didn't work I looked for other solutions.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific about your issue, e.g., what command you're trying to run. Also, you should go to Homebrew's issue tracker instead.

Comment: there aren't many commands available to use if one want to install homebrew ... but I updated my post, just for you.

Comment: There's nothing in the install script that uses rbenv. You probably just have a botched ruby from rbenv installed somewhere. Try `/usr/bin/ruby -e ...` instead.